# Change Connection String at runtime in VB

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, connection-string

I am developing a Windows Forms VB Project that will allow users to connect to a remote SQL Server database to enter and edit data. During development I have been using the integrated connection string to connect to the SQL Server instance.

At this time, I need to add a login box that would modify the connection string and adjust their data access accordingly. I have the form set up to get the username and password and confirm their login credentials against the Server, but I am having problems modifying the global connection string for my project. I am using Visual Studio 1017. I would appreciate any assistance or suggestions.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at [Connection String Builders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-builders).

Comment: What's you goal here? Do you want to prompt/validate/use user entered credentials each time your program runs or do you want to prompt/validate them *once* and then save the value somewhere that can be reused each time the program runs?

Comment: How can you build your application to allow a connection to any database? Unless this application is some sort of utility to view the structure and such it seems like a combobox of valid databases would be a better approach. Then the user doesn't need to know the connection details, just which database they want to connect to.

Comment: To clarify: Damien:I want to prompt/validate/use user entered credentials each time the program runs. - Sean: I only want to modify the username/pword part of the connection string. The rest remains static.

Comment: Ahh gotcha. So each user has their own database login. So what is the issue? Do you have a global connection string variable or something? Really hard to offer much help with no context of what you are doing.

Comment: I have the connection string defined in Project Settings with my username and password included, but it does not allow that variable to be changed during runtime. I need to have each user enter their own username/password and connect using that.Sorry - I'm kinda new to this, so maybe I am missing an easy fix...?

Comment: Well changing the project settings would be rather problematic wouldn't it? You probably want to store this in a global variable which can be changed during runtime. But I am not a big fan of global variables. I would probably address a bit differently and use windows authentication to the database. Then you don't need to manage this so tediously.

Comment: I'm not a pro in this, but is it maybe an idea to make a database with users their username and password and a connectionstring?
So if they login it would use that connectionstring.
and an option that they can change their own connectionstring if needed.

Comment: Thanks Sean, but unfortunately this will not be used in a domain environment so Windows Authentication won't work. However, I found this link I may try: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19578/How-to-persist-changes-to-My-Settings-ConnectionSt